# How would you get to $\tan(\theta/2)$ if you are given $\sin\theta/(1+\cos\theta)$?

Tags: trigonometry

According to wolfram alpha, ${\sin{\theta}\over{1+\cos{\beta}}}={\tan{\theta\over2}}$.
But how would you get to ${\tan{\theta\over2}}$ if you're given ${\sin{\theta}\over{1+\cos{\beta}}}$?

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\sin \theta}{1+\cos \theta} &= \dfrac{2 \sin \frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac\theta2}{2\cos^2\frac\theta2} =\tan\frac\theta2\end{align}$$

$\sin\theta = \sin(\frac\theta2+\frac\theta2) = \sin\frac\theta2 \cos\frac\theta2 + \cos\frac\theta2 \sin\frac\theta2 = 2\sin\frac\theta2 \cos\frac\theta2$

using $\sin(\alpha+\beta) = \sin\alpha\cos\beta + \cos\alpha\sin\beta$

$\cos\theta = \cos(\frac\theta2+\frac\theta2) = \cos\frac\theta2\cos\frac\theta2-\sin\frac\theta2\sin\frac\theta2 = \cos^2\frac\theta2 - \sin^2\frac\theta2 = 2\cos^2\frac\theta2-1$

using $\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta -\sin\alpha\sin\beta$

Answer (score 3):

It's a special case of the general identity $\tan\frac{a+b}{2} = \frac{\sin a+\sin b}{\cos a+\cos b}$, where $a=0$.

[image: Diagram of this trig identity]

Comment: great result!...

Comment: Is the every thick like of the length $1$? Also, why is the angle of the parallelogram $\frac{a+b}{2}$

Comment: @taninamdar: Yes, the fat lines have length $1$. That makes the parallelogram a _rhombus_, which means that the diagonal bisects the corner angles. So the direction of the diagonal is halfway between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The $\cos((a+b)/2)$ and $\sin((a+b)/2)$ in the figure are wrong, by the way -- they should be scaled by then length of the diagonal. But their _ratio_ is what we're after anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $\tan \frac{\theta}2=t$, then $\sin \theta = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$  and $\cos \theta = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$